# Flash Builder 4.7: There is no html-template page when I create an Actionscript AIR project...how do I debug?

Tags: actionscript, air, flash-builder, project, wmode

I am starting out with Flash Builder for the first time (I have 4.7) and I used to use Flash. I'm trying out a game project for Starling in the mobile development. So I created an Actionscript Project and made the target desktop for Adobe Air. Now to debug it, I always get the error wmode is not set correctly. Every tutorial I have run across has said edit the html-template page to add in wmode=direct. Except when I created the project I have no html-template page. I have the app xml page but that is for a different purpose. I can't create or destroy the html-wrapper page in the Actionscript compiler options in the properties window as there is no option for that. Adding the wmode to the swf metadata on my main as file does nothing. I can't even add a new run or debug mobile application configuration because there is no project to be selected for New Configuration.

So what am I missing? How do I debug this project on a pc? How do I set the wmode or get past this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it under the "Project1-app.xml" file (Project1 is whatever you named it).  If you scroll down to

```
< !-- < renderMode>< /renderMode> -->
```

delete the

```
< !-- part and the -->
```

part then add "direct" in between.  So it should look like the following:

```
< renderMode>direct< /renderMode>
```

it should turn greenish when you do it